# FLASK with Jquery and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, flask

I have watched a tutorial about how to make an editable table with JSON, Jquery and PHP and it seems to be adaptable into Flask except the last function which is: $.getJSON(url+input, function(data) in my JS file (you can see this at the bottom of JS file). When I click on the editable table and change the text inside and press enter it says in the browser debug console that : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). I think it is about the url problem but why in the tutorial it works fine but for me it is not http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FNyIz37j3I

Can the Flask use serialise function? or it is about the way I define the url have to be changed because the routing system in Flask and in the tutorial are different?

I know that this can be done a lot easier with HTML5 but I really want to study this process because it will be very useful for me to know.

JS file:

```
 $(function(){

 $('tbody').on('click', 'td', function() {

    displayForm( $(this) );

 });


function displayForm (cell) {

var column = cell.attr('name'),
    id = cell.closest('tr').attr('id'),
    cellWidth = cell.css('width')
    prevContent = cell.text(),
    form = '<form action="javascript: this.preventDefault"><input type="text" name="newValue" size= "4" value="'+prevContent+'"/><input type="hidden" name="id" value= "'+id+'" />'+'<input type="hidden" name="column" value="'+column+'"/></form>';

cell.html(form).find('input[type=text]')
.focus()
.css('width', cellWidth);

cell.on('click', function() {return false;});

cell.on('keydown', function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        changeField(cell, prevContent);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        cell.text(prevContent);
        cell.off('click');
    }

});
}

function changeField(cell, prevContent) {

cell.off('keydown');

var url = '/jsonurl',
    input = cell.find('form').serialize();


$.getJSON(url+input, function(data){

    if (data.success)
        cell.html(data.value);
    else {
        alert('There was a problem updating the data.');
        cell.html(prevContent);
    }

});

cell.off('click');

}
});
```

and this is in the Python file:

```
@app.route('/jsonurl')
def jsonurl():
    column = request.args.GET('column')
    id = request.args.GET('id')
    newValue = request.args.GET('newValue')

    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('UPDATE customer SET column = newValue WHERE rowid=id')
    g.db.commit()
    g.db.close()
    return jsonify(success=True, value=newValue)
```

HTML file:

```
{% for item in customer %}

<tr id={{ item.rowid }}> <td class="name" > {{ item.name }} </td> <td class="lastname"> {{ item.lastname }} </td> </tr>     


    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but the way you're concatenating that url to send your form data to, you're concatenating "url + input", url being "/jsonurl" and input being the form's serialized data, which is going to be in the form of "field1=value1&field2=value2", etc. The serialize function doesn't prepend the question mark to the data, you have to provide that yourself, so the current way your url would be constructed would look like this: "/jsonurlfield1=value1&field2=value2", and it would be sending the form data to "/jsonurlfield1" instead of "/jsonurl". Try adding the ampersand yourseld, like "url + '?' + input".

Comment: ok I have put ? into var url = '/jsonurl?' now it says [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (jsonurl, line 0)

Comment: When I click it explain more about this:   File "/Users/Team/Desktop/Flask/routes.py", line 72, in jsonurl
    column = request.args.GET('column')
AttributeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object has no attribute 'GET'
what this mean ^^" sorry I'm newbie and totally lost with this